# How to add item into array and make it appear at the top, without triggering multiple digest cycles?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, push

http://plnkr.co/edit/HgjGS9LSZ0VhyBMkwy6L?p=preview

```
vs.unshift = function() {
    vs.feedList.unshift(unshifted_item);
};

vs.push = function() {
    vs.feedList.push(push_item);
};
```

In our real app with APIs, when I use `unshift` to add a new alert into the alerts feed (via websockets) the item takes forever to get added to the top of the array because of the digest cycle. It seems to iterate over every time in the array by the amount of items in the array (ie: 10x10), before it finally adds the item to the top of the array.

However if we use `push` the new alert is immediately added because Angular does not have to check all the other items in the array first.

This problem is hard to replicate in the plnkr example I created above, because the unshift instantly adds the item to the top of the array. However, how can one use `push` and then move the item that was pushed to the top of the array without causing a digest cycle?

Comment: Im not that familiar with angular.js, but this may be an issue because _Array.prototype.unshift()_ returns the new length of the array. In your case it seems that you dont even want to know the new length. However, you could always use _Array.prototype.splice()_ to not only remove items but to add them. So basicly: _vs.feedList.splice(0,0,unshifted_item)_

Comment: Can you not make `vs.feedList = [unshifted_item].concat(vs.feedList);` or `vs.feedList.splice(0,0,unshifted_item);`

Comment: Nice! The `.splice(0,0` method worked! Care to explain what is going on there in an Answer? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Redu suggested, the splice method works without causing the Angular digest cycle to hang.

`feedList.splice(0, 0, item)`